# SFINAE - Falling back on default function if more sophisticated one fails

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

Say I have written a generic function called `interpolate`. Its signature is like so:

```
template<typename T>
T interpolate(T a, T b, float c);
```

Where a and b are the values to interpolate between, and c is a float in [0.0,1.0].

Iff T has `T operator*(float)` and `T operator+(T)` defined, I would like this to behave a certain way (linear interpolation). Otherwise, it would behave differently - in such a way that any `T` is useable(nearest neighbor interpolation).

How can I achieve this behavior?

For example:

```
interpolate<std::string>("hello","world!", 0.798); //uses nearest neighbor, as std::string does not have the necessary operators

interpolate<double>(42.0,128.0, 0.5);              //uses linear, as double has the needed operators
```

*Note: this question is not on the implementation of these interpolation methods, just how to use templates to switch behavior of a function.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a prime use case for *tag dispatching*:

We create two different tag classes to distinguish between the two use cases

```
struct linear_tag {};
struct nn_tag {};

template <typename T>
T impl(T a, T b, float c, linear_tag) {
    // linear interpolation here
}

template <typename T>
T impl(T a, T b, float c, nn_tag) {
    // nearest neighbor interpolation here
}
```

Now, we need to find out the tag type from `T`:

```
template <typename T>
linear_tag tag_for(
    T* p,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, decltype((*p + *p) * 0.5)>>* = nullptr
);
nn_tag tag_for(...); // Fallback
```

The first overload only exists if, for any `T t`, the expression `(t + t) * 0.5f` returns another `T`.<sup>1</sup> The second overload always exists, but because of the C-style variadic argument, it is never used unless the first overload doesn't match.

Then, we can dispatch to either version by creating the appropriate tag:

```
template <typename T>
T interpolate(T a, T b, float c) {
    return impl(a, b, c, decltype(tag_for(static_cast<T*>(nullptr))){});
}
```

Here, `decltype(tag_for(static_cast<T*>(nullptr)))` gives us the right tag type (as the return type of the correct overload of `tag_for`).

You can add additional tag types with very little overhead, and test for arbitrarily complex conditions in the `enable_if_t`. This particular version is C++17 only (because of `is_same_v`), but you can just as easily make it C++11-compatible by using `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` and `std::is_same<...>::value` instead - it's just a bit more verbose.

<sup><sup>1</sup> This is what you specified in the question - but it is dangerous! If you use integers, for example, you will use nearest-neighbor interpolation because `*` returns `float`, not `int`. You should instead test if the expression `(*t + *t) * 0.5f` returns something that is *convertible* back to `T` using a test such as `std::is_constructible_v<T, decltype((*t + *t) * 0.5f)>`</sup>

---

As a bonus, here is a [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) concepts-based implementation that doesn't need tags anymore (as briefly mentioned in the comments). Unfortunately, there is no compiler that supports `requires` on this level yet, and of course the draft standard is always subject to change:

```
template <typename T>
concept LinearInterpolatable = requires(T a, T b, float c) {
    { a + b } -> T;
    { a * c } -> T;
};

template <LinearInterpolatable T>
T interpolate(T a, T b, float c)
{
    // Linear interpolation
}

template <typename T>
T interpolate(T a, T b, float c)
{
    // Nearest-neighbor interpolation
}
```

Comment: Woah! That's a lot more complex than I would've expected it to be! Thank you so much for writing this out - I could learn a whole lot from what you've showed me here :)

Comment: It's an extremely powerful and flexible feature - the standard library uses it to distinguish between different types of iterators with different feature sets via the [`iterator_category`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags)

Comment: If you're using C++17, you can also use `if constexpr` rather overloaded functions for `impl`

Comment: That is possible, but would require an additional template for the tag type, at which point I think it is cleaner to just let the compiler do the type equality checks. With C++20 we'll get concepts (maybe), which will hopefully allow us to do this without the entire dispatching part.

Comment: why do you use C-style cast in `decltype(tag_for((T*) nullptr))`?

Comment: @AndriyTylychko Bad old habit of mine. Replaced it with `static_cast`

Comment: @Justin Unfortunately for me, I can't find a compiler with support for over c++11 :( I'm sure if I could, I could find a lot of more elegant ways to do things when it comes to templates!

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to provide an order of preference for overloaded functions. If the number of overloads is small, you can just use:

```
using prefer_overload_t = int;
using backup_overload_t = long;

template <typename T>
auto interpolate_impl(T a, T b, float c, prefer_overload_t)
    -> std::enable_if_t<
           std::is_same_v<T, decltype(a * c)>
           && std::is_same_v<T, decltype(a + b)>,
           T
       >
{
    // linear interpolation
}

template <typename T>
T interpolate_impl(T a, T b, float c, backup_overload_t)
{
    // nearest neighbor
}

template<typename T>
T interpolate(T a, T b, float c)
{
    return interpolate_impl(std::move(a), std::move(b), c, prefer_overload_t());
}
```

Since it requires no conversion to go from `int` to `int`, the former overload is preferred, but is SFINAE'd out when it doesn't work.

---

If you want to order an arbitrary number of overloads, you'd have to use some special type like this:

```
template <std::size_t N>
struct rank : rank<N - 1>
{};

template <>
struct rank<0>
{};
```

Then, `rank<N>` would be preferred over `rank<N - 1>`.